# What's the difference between Joi.object().keys() and append() methods in terms of adding more keys

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I have this piece of code

```
const baseSchema = Joi.object.keys({
   name: Joi.string().required()
})
```

Now I want to add more keys to this schema, I can write

```
const basicInfoSchema = baseSchema.keys({
   address: Joi.string().required(),
   phoneNumber: Joi.number().required()
})
```

or

```
const basicInfoSchema = baseSchema.append({
   address: Joi.string().required(),
   phoneNumber: Joi.number().required()
})
```

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` has a generic parameter to give some typing to the expected object. Like `Joi.object<>()` does. `keys` has no generic parameter.

Also looking at the source code bellow (version 17.6.0), you can see append calls `keys` under the hood. I won't paste the documentation, but you can read it there https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0 .

Basically, `append` only do the `else` clause of `keys` method. While `keys` can also "Allow all" (any key allowed) or "Allow none" (no keys allowed) of the existing keys. `keys` has two extra functionalities.

```js
        append: {
            method(schema) {

                if (schema === null ||
                    schema === undefined ||
                    Object.keys(schema).length === 0) {

                    return this;
                }

                return this.keys(schema);
            }
        },
```

```js
        keys: {
            method(schema) {

                Assert(schema === undefined || typeof schema === 'object', 'Object schema must be a valid object');
                Assert(!Common.isSchema(schema), 'Object schema cannot be a joi schema');

                const obj = this.clone();

                if (!schema) {                                      // Allow all
                    obj.$_terms.keys = null;
                }
                else if (!Object.keys(schema).length) {             // Allow none
                    obj.$_terms.keys = new internals.Keys();
                }
                else {
                    obj.$_terms.keys = obj.$_terms.keys ? obj.$_terms.keys.filter((child) => !schema.hasOwnProperty(child.key)) : new internals.Keys();
                    for (const key in schema) {
                        Common.tryWithPath(() => obj.$_terms.keys.push({ key, schema: this.$_compile(schema[key]) }), key);
                    }
                }

                return obj.$_mutateRebuild();
            }
        },
```